# What is the windows equivalent for envsubst in linux

Tags: windows, bash, shell, environment-variables

I use envsubst to substitute environment variables to a file in linux.

```
envsubst < task-definition.json > new-task-definition.json
```

How to achieve this feature in windows using default resources or using a 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't directly know of a built in substitute for the `envsubst` command in Windows. However as you've made 3rd party tools an option, I would recommend [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), a minimalist GNU package for Windows users. It also comes with a `envsubst` implementation for Windows.

[CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) could also be an option. It provides a more complete collection of GNU tools and other Open Source tools for Windows (comes also with a POSIX API for Windows for example). It should also have an `envsubst` but as I don't have CygWin locally I cannot confirm this.

I would go for MinGW though as the extra functionnalities CygWin provides (POSIX environment) are not needed for `envsubst` but the choice is up to you ([this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771756/what-is-the-difference-between-cygwin-and-mingw) and [this article](http://www.electrobucket.com/general/mingw-and-cygwin-an-introduction-and-differences) may help you make a decision).

Answer (score 1):

There *are* a couple of cross-platform implementations of this (written in go) available on github which *are* compatible with envsubst, and add some extra tricks.

Drone has one with neat tricks like changing the case of the value or doing regex replacements, but has no binary releases:

https://github.com/drone/envsubst

a8m has binary releases, and supports defaults and fallback values:

https://github.com/a8m/envsubst/releases

### Also, as @rchekaluk suggested, PowerShell can safely expand variables.

It does so using *PowerShell* variables, so if you want to use *environment* variables you either have to name them like `${env:USERNAME}` (or `$Env:UserName`) (which would be incompatible with envsubst), or you have to copy the environment variables into PowerShell variables first:

```
Get-ChildItem Env: | Set-Variable
```

The safe way to expand variables in a string in PowerShell is to use:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($String)
```

So we could put it together in a roughly compatible way:

```
function envsubst {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)][string]$InputObject)

  Get-ChildItem Env: | Set-Variable
  $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($InputObject)
}

cat template.yaml | envsubst > result.yaml
```

Comment: That's a neat solution! Although worth noting, The `Get-ChildItem Env: | Set-Variable` command could create overhead if there are many environment variables, since it's creating a local PowerShell variable for *each* environment variable. This might not be a significant concern in most cases though. Also, as it sets every environment variable as a local variable, there could be potential name clashes if there are other local variables with the same name. But still a good solution that should work just fine out-of-the-box :)

Comment: Name clashes _should not_ matter. PowerShell variables are scoped (local by default), so these variables would not affect anything else. There will be weird edge cases if you have an Environment variable using the name of a PowerShell constant, like "True" or "Null". Of course, drone envsubst has a lot of ... extra functionality ;)

Answer (score 0):

Packet in Ubuntu/Debian `gettext-base` has `envsubst` with same functional.

[Online documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) for `envsubst` in `gettext` project.

Answer (score 0):

`Git Bash` terminal on Windows has support for `envsubst`

Answer (score 0):

**Envsubst Equivalent for Windows using PowerShell**

There isn't a direct substitute for `envsubst` built into Windows, but you can achieve similar functionality with PowerShell. Here's a batch script you can use to replace environment variable references in the format `${VARIABLE_NAME}` in a file:

```
@echo off
setlocal

powershell -NoProfile -Command "$content = Get-Content -Path inputfile.txt -Raw; $matches = [regex]::Matches($content, '\$\{([^}]+)\}'); foreach ($match in $matches) { $varName = $match.Groups[1].Value; $replacement = (Get-Item -LiteralPath \"Env:$varName\").Value; $content = $content.Replace($match.Value, $replacement); } Set-Content -Path outputfile.txt -Value $content;"

endlocal
```

You'll need to modify `inputfile.txt` and `outputfile.txt` to the appropriate paths. When executed, the script will replace instances of `${VARIABLE_NAME}` in `inputfile.txt` with the corresponding environment variable's value and output the result to `outputfile.txt`.

This approach uses native PowerShell capabilities and doesn't rely on third-party tools or utilities, making it a portable solution for Windows users.

Here's the breakdown of the script, section by section:

#### 1. Batch Script Initiation and Context Setup

```
@echo off
```

This command suppresses the echoing or displaying of commands as they are executed in the batch file.

```
setlocal
```

This command ensures that the environment changes (like variable assignments) in the script are local to the batch file. Without `setlocal`, any environment variable changes would affect the command shell that launched the batch file.

#### 2. PowerShell Execution

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "..."
```

This invokes the PowerShell interpreter from within the batch script. The `-NoProfile` flag ensures that no user-specific profiles or configurations are loaded, guaranteeing a consistent environment. The `-Command` flag specifies the PowerShell commands that will be executed, enclosed in double quotes. If the command was on multiple lines, the batch script would assume each line is a separate batch function, and not part of the PowerShell command. So it is all on one line.

#### 3. Reading the Input File

```
$content = Get-Content -Path inputfile.txt -Raw;
```

This line uses the `Get-Content` cmdlet to read the entire contents of `inputfile.txt` into the `$content` variable. The `-Raw` parameter ensures that the entire file is read as a single string, as opposed to an array of lines.

#### 4. Finding Matches for Environment Variable References

```
$matches = [regex]::Matches($content, '\$\{([^}]+)\}');
```

Here, we're using .NET's regex class to find all instances in `$content` that match the `${VARIABLE_NAME}` pattern. Each match found will be stored in the `$matches` variable.

#### 5. Iterating Over Matches and Performing Replacement

```
foreach ($match in $matches) { ... }
```

This is a loop that goes through each match found in the previous step.

```
$varName = $match.Groups[1].Value;
```

From each match, we extract the variable name. The `[1]` refers to the first capture group in the regex, which corresponds to `VARIABLE_NAME`.

```
$replacement = (Get-Item -LiteralPath \"Env:$varName\").Value;
```

For each variable name, this line fetches its corresponding value from the environment variables.

```
$content = $content.Replace($match.Value, $replacement);
```

In the `$content` string, this line replaces the `${VARIABLE_NAME}` pattern with its corresponding environment variable value.

#### 6. Writing the Modified Content to the Output File

```
Set-Content -Path outputfile.txt -Value $content;
```

This writes the modified `$content` (with variables substituted) to `outputfile.txt`.

#### 7. Closing the Local Context

```
endlocal
```

This batch command restores the environment to its state before the script was started, ensuring any variable changes or modifications made within the script don't affect the calling shell.

---

Together, these parts create a script that can replace `${VARIABLE_NAME}` patterns in a file with their corresponding environment variable values on a Windows machine using PowerShell. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

See [PowerTip: Expand Environmental Variables with PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-expand-environmental-variables-with-powershell/)

Comment: Link only answer is useless. Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.